# React pdf generator with transform, scale, rotate and more

Tags: reactjs, pdf, puppeteer

I'm testing and looking forward into some solutions like react-pdf and others. But what I really need is to use css properties like transform, translate and more like scale and rotate for example.

Do You heard about som kinda solutions, maybe someone just used something like?

I'll be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all future searcher:

I tried react-pdf and html-pdf, but they were not solutions that would suit me completely.
There was always a lack of either transition, transform or svg support. In addition, they required writing an additional pdf template from which to generate.

So, ultimately, I used a node library called **Puppeteer**, based on chromium, thanks to which you can generate a pdf just like in the preview on the chrome browser, and regardless of which browser we use.

Puppeter is in fact a Headless Chrome ('running Chrome without chrome') solution, which enters the address we want and performs actions without the participation of the user, in this case writing to a pdf file.

Link: [https://pptr.dev/]

Link: [Headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome)